# Looking to change from Octalink Claris to Shimano 105, will the frame be compatible with a 105 hub?

Tags: road-bike, shimano, gears, mechanical, groupsets

Since road bikes are sold out almost everywhere. I was thinking about upgrading my current road bike with a new group set. My current bike a Scott Speedster 50 (2015) currently has a Shimano Claris groupset Octalink. I'm looking to change out the groupset to a 105, my worry is that the 105 hub or groupset will not be compatible with my frame. Can anyone please tell me if it is possible to install a 105 groupset on a Claris Octalink compatible frame.

Thank you for all your help!

Answer (score 1):

Octalink is the bottom bracket spindle interface. It's kind of muddying the waters to focus on this. If you have all Claris parts of that era, the commonly understood way of referring to it would be 2400, Claris 2400, etc. (There's a newer Claris now.)

Straightforward modern rim brake road bikes like that generally can have whatever group you want dropped in. Going to 11 will mean needing a new rear hub/wheel in most such cases. It should be fine.