# Is this groupset compatible with my Salsa Journeyer?

Tags: shimano, compatibility, groupsets

I recently purchased a Salsa Journeyer with a Shimano Claris groupset. I was wondering in the near future if I could change the groupset to the Shimano 105 R7000? I am new to cycling so not sure if this is a dumb question.

Comment: There are no dumb questions.    Possibly relevant, though not a duplicate    https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/75625/looking-to-change-from-octalink-claris-to-shimano-105-will-the-frame-be-compati

Answer (score 1):

Probably best to get a couple years riding on the current groupset before contemplating expensive replacements.   Most people generally don't buy a new car then immediately replace an engine, for example.   Your take-off parts have minimal wear and could be on-sold, but nowhere near enough to cover the cost.

In a couple years you will have more idea what kind of riding you want to do, and whether a mid/upperrange groupset like 105 suits that compared to claris which is good entry level groupset.

If you do change groupset, you'll need to replace your shifters/brake levers, deraillers, cassette, chain, maybe cranks.  You won't have to replace brake calipers or inner/outer cables.   All together, this is a respectable fraction of the cost of the bike.

Claris is 8 speed, so theres a possibility your 11 speed cassette won't fit, which may mean a new rear wheel hub too, and either a wheel rebuild or a new wheel.

Comment: Thanks for the quick and detailed response! I figured as a new cyclist, this bike and groupset would suit me. But didn't take much for me to really get into this. Just wanted to look at some options to the great frame that salsa makes.